# Color of the text is not changing when style including textColor is applied to textAppearance of textView

Tags: android, text, android-styles, textcolor, appearance

I want to reduce my xml code repetition. So I made some standard styles for text in textView. We can apply styles under 'style' attribute as well as 'android:textAppearance' attribute in textView.

Below are some styles I made for text appearance-

```
<style name="Grey">
    <item name="android:textColor"> #333333 </item>
</style>

<style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor"> #00FF00 </item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

When I apply these styles under 'textAppearance' attribute the color of the text is not changing in none of the above styles. It's working under 'style' attribute of textView.

```
//textColor not working
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Full Name"
    android:textAppearance="@style/CodeFont"/>

//textColor working
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Full Name"
    style="@style/CodeFont"/>
```

I want them to work under 'textAppearance' attribute so that I can apply some other style under 'style' attribute. And according to [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) we can apply textColor styles under 'textAppearance' attribute.

Please suggest some solution to this.
Thanks

Comment: textColor is most likely overriden by default TextView style, as style has precedence over textAppearance. To check this you can set android:textColor="@null" before the line android:textAppearance="@style/CodeFont".

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the text color in your widget as null like this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/profile_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Full Name"
android:textColor="@null"  //add this line
android:textAppearance="@style/CodeFont"/>
```

Also, I think you should try to Invalidate cache and Restart Android Studio. Import and linking issues can be solved like this sometimes.

Comment: Try Clean Build and Invalidate Cache and Restart

Answer (score 2):

This snippet works for me

```
 <style name="fonts" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">#245546</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
</style>
```

and textview is

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to stackoverflow"
    android:textAppearance="@style/fonts"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you don't give `android:textColor` in styles you can have this issue that text color won't appear in your **TextView**, So the solution is to just give completely `<item name="android:textColor">@color/yourColor</item>` in styles rather than this `<item name="textColor">@color/yourColor</item>`.. your problem would be resolved :)