# TextView is not setting textstyle, color and anything

Tags: android

I am setting style,color and  size to textview , that is working 
this is my code `

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
android:id="@+id/txt_agent_code"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"                     
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="14sp"          
android:textStyle="italic"/>
```

Comment: Welcome please edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask what issue you face ? first set text size with dimens or textAttr don't use fix size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color of the text is not changing when style including textColor is applied to textAppearance of textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007858/color-of-the-text-is-not-changing-when-style-including-textcolor-is-applied-to-t)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your parent layout is correct some times transparent layer or such things create visualise problem with colour

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_agent_code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="AppCompatTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="114dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Use [Dimension](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) for setting up a text size ,always avoid hard coding

[image]

If you want to set same style for text-color,text-size and text-style than you can create something like

```
<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>       
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_body_1_material</item>
    <item name="textColor">?textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```